# Alternativas para armazenar e analisar dados

Tags: python, estrutura-de-dados

Uma parte de um projeto que estou desenvolvendo é adquirir dados de tensão e corrente de uma placa solar. Por dia eu tenho em torno de 40 medidas como estas que estão aqui.

```
14/dez  16:54   18.21   0.12    18.35   0.0641
14/dez  16:54   17.82   0.27    17.98   0.2041
14/dez  16:54   17.42   0.44    17.61   0.3041
14/dez  16:54   14.23   0.39    15.30   0.3841
14/dez  16:54   5.92    0.63    7.45    0.6741
14/dez  16:54   4.97    0.54    6.50    0.6441
14/dez  16:54   4.56    0.48    5.91    0.5641
14/dez  16:54   3.51    0.68    4.59    0.7541
14/dez  16:55   2.32    0.60    2.97    0.6841
14/dez  16:55   2.19    0.51    2.76    0.6041
14/dez  16:55   2.13    0.44    2.67    0.5041
14/dez  16:55   0.71    0.67    0.90    0.7641
14/dez  16:55   0.61    0.64    0.77    0.7441
14/dez  16:55   0.00    0.69    0.00    0.821

15/dez  06:04   17.67   0.13    17.61   0.051
15/dez  06:04   15.82   0.25    15.82   0.181
15/dez  06:04   12.41   0.30    13.00   0.231
15/dez  06:04   8.09    0.22    8.72    0.161
15/dez  06:04   2.84    0.31    3.11    0.281
15/dez  06:04   2.38    0.25    2.60    0.191
15/dez  06:04   2.19    0.17    2.40    0.111
15/dez  06:04   1.69    0.36    1.79    0.301
15/dez  06:04   1.07    0.27    1.16    0.241
15/dez  06:04   1.02    0.21    1.10    0.171
15/dez  06:05   1.01    0.10    1.09    0.061
15/dez  06:05   0.33    0.32    0.35    0.311
15/dez  06:05   0.28    0.29    0.30    0.251
15/dez  06:05   0.00    0.33    0.00    0.312
```

Eu tenho que armazenar esses dados de modo que no futuro seja possível traçar gráficos escolhendo o dia e hora por exemplo.

O que quero é armazenar e depois recuperar os dados mais ou menos desta forma:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
Ex grosseiro para recuperar: plot(data['14/12'].hora['07:00'].medidas)
```

Alguém sabe se da pra fazer isso usando banco de dados? Ou sugere outra solução para armazenar?

Se for em Python seria ainda melhor.

Obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para este exemplo coloquei (armazenei) exatamente os dados que colocaste num ficheiro e fui percorre-lo e retirar os dados, sendo que este ficheiro (`tests.txt`) está na mesma pasta do ficheiro com o código, podes tambem colocar (armazenar) num `ficheiro.csv`:

```
dados = {}
with open('tests.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        params = [i.strip() for i in line.split('  ') if i.strip() != '']
        if not params:
            continue
        data, hora, v1, l1, v2, l2 = params
        dados[data] = dados.get(data, {})
        dados[data][hora] = dados[data].get(hora, [])
        dados[data][hora].append((v1, l1, v2, l2))
```

Nesta linha `[i.strip() for i in line.split('  ') if i.strip() != '']`. Nota que se puderes ficaria muito mais simples separar os dados por linha por só ex: ";" que ficaria: `[i.strip() for i in line.split(';')]` em vez de espaços inconstantes como puseste, e sem linhas vazias também se poderia retirar a verificação, `if not params: continue`.

No entanto este código é totalmente funcional para os dados/formato que colocaste

Consegues aceder a cada dia e/ou hora assim:

Dia:

```
print(dados['15/dez'])
```

Output:

> {'06:05': [('1.01', '0.33', '0.28', '0.00'), ('0.10', '0.32', '0.29', '0.33'), ('1.09', '0.35', '0.30', '0.00'), ('0.061', '0.311', '0.251', '0.312')], '06:04': [('17.67', '0.13', '17.61', '0.051'), ('15.82', '0.25', '15.82', '0.181'), ('12.41', '0.30', '13.00', '0.231'), ('8.09', '0.22', '8.72', '0.161'), ('2.84', '0.31', '3.11', '0.281'), ('2.38', '0.25', '2.60', '0.191'), ('2.19', '0.17', '2.40', '0.111'), ('1.69', '0.36', '1.79', '0.301'), ('1.07', '0.27', '1.16', '0.241'), ('1.02', '0.21', '1.10', '0.171')]}

Hora (aqui acedes às várias medidas de cada hora):

```
print(dados['15/dez']['06:05'])
```

Output:

> [('1.01', '0.33', '0.28', '0.00'), ('0.10', '0.32', '0.29', '0.33'), ('1.09', '0.35', '0.30', '0.00'), ('0.061', '0.311', '0.251', '0.312')]

Aqui vou deixar uma alternativa usando [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import [defaultdict][1]

dados = defaultdict(dict)
with open('tests.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        params = [i.strip() for i in line.split('  ') if i.strip() != '']
        if not params:
            continue
        data, hora, v1, l1, v2, l2 = params
        if hora not in dados[data]:
            dados[data][hora] = []
        dados[data][hora].append((v1, l1, v2, l2))
print(dados)
```

Comment: Cara, valeu mesmo! Já deu pra ter uma noção. Ajustando uma coisa ou outra ali acho que da certo.
Vou tentar deixar cada bloco como uma única leitura, e fazer v1,i1 = lista com 14 elementos. 
Abraço

Comment: @thiagorls deves aceitar a resposta se te foi a que te ajudou, por baixo das setas à esquerda da resposta. Bem vindo ao stack overflow pt. Para fazeres um unico bloco com os valores troca `...append(...` por `...extend(...`

Comment: Feito, obrigado!

Comment: de nada @thiagorls, ainda bem que ajudei

Comment: Só uma última coisa @Miguel, to tentando fazer dados ser `{'06:04': [(Todos os valores de v1), (todos os valores de i1), (todos v2), (todos i2)]}` em vez de `{hora: [(v1,i1,v2,i2), (v1,i1,v2,i2)]}` ou todos juntos como você deu a dica usando o extend. Alguma dica?

Comment: @thiagorls, vou colocar isso. 5 mins

Comment: @thiagorls, aqui está http://ideone.com/u13mxK

Comment: valeu mesmo cara, me ajudou bastante. Sou realmente grato!

Comment: De nada @thiagorls, acho que era isso que querias

Comment: Era sim @Miguel !!

Answer (score 0):

Dá sim, mas acho desnecessário usar um banco de dados, visto que você não parecer ter muita experiência com isso.

Pesquise sobre CSV, você pode guardar seus dados em um .txt salvo dentro do projeto mesmo, quando precisar de novo é só reabrir o csv. Há diversas bibliotecas em python para te auxiliar no gerenciamento de arquivos CSV, é a forma mais fácil de se armazenar dados pequenos.

Caso queira um banco de dados você pode usar o Firebase, funciona pela nuvem e é bem simples de se usar. Para bancos locais recomendo SQLite.